# Why multiple file copying takes long time?

Tags: windows, file-copying

I have to move around 200000 (`pdf`) files from one drive to external drive to free up my disk space.. When i started copying files its showing `18` hours remaining. If start copying all files of (around `350 GB`) at time will it cause any problem ? .....

when i copy `1 GB` data of single video file it's taking less time when i am trying to transfer same `1 GB` of multiple `pdf` files ... What is the reason behind this one ? can any one help on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have issues trying to make the UI responsive and calculate time to copy. but i have seen their estimates are always off. seems they over estimate how long it will take to copy to external drives and USBs. So don't worry about it and just copy!

When i have copied to a USB have noticed that it takes just 20% more time as it would take copying between drives.

If you want to copy faster use the command prompt.

[Copy command in command prompt (how to use)](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/#commands%20look%20for%20Copy)

[Basics command promot](http://people.uncw.edu/pattersone/121/labs/L1_MSDOS_Primer.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> First thing this is not a programming related question.

[Are You Asking This](https://superuser.com/questions/344534/why-does-copying-the-same-amount-of-data-take-longer-if-spread-across-many-separ)

Answer (score 0):

Windows has two separate things that cost time: Copying the actual data, and creating a new remote file entry. The copying of data is a fairly fast process and Windows will saturate your network connection or USB connection quickly. The creating of new files is a much less rapid thing in Windows, especially for remote shares. This causes many small files that are together not too large to still take a long time.